# Sorted linked-list in C (self-compiling)

Tags: c, linked-list

I needed a sorted-list that I can iterate over to render elements in layers. Right now, `delete_item` deletes the first node with a matching priority it finds but I intend to delete specific list items in my implementation.

I didn't know if I needed the list to be doubly linked, but it turns out it makes deleting an item from the list easier. I've also seen people initializing the memory with `calloc`, is it important in this case?

There's also probably a way to give each list item a unique identifier (apart from its pointer) so that I can delete a specific item instead of deleting the first occurrence. For now, I'll just use the pointer...

Also, what do you think of my self-compiling trick?

```
//usr/bin/gcc ${0##*/} -o temp && ./temp ; rm temp 2>/dev/null ; exit

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;

    int priority;
};

struct node *head;

void add_item(int priority)
{
    struct node *curr = head;
    struct node *prev = NULL;

    while((curr != NULL) && (curr->priority < priority)) {
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    struct node *new = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new->priority = priority;
    new->next = curr;
    new->prev = prev;

    if(prev != NULL) {
        prev->next = new;
    } else {
        head = new;
    }
}

void remove_item(int priority)
{
    struct node *curr = head;
    while((curr != NULL) && (curr->priority != priority)) {
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    if(!curr)
        return;

    if(curr == head) {
        head = curr->next;
    } else {
        curr->prev->next = curr->next;
        if(curr->next)
            curr->next->prev = curr->prev;
    }
    free(curr);
}

void delete_list()
{
    struct node *curr;
    while(head != NULL) {
        curr = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(curr);
    }
}

void print_items()
{
    int member = 0;
    for(struct node *iter = head; iter != NULL; iter = iter->next)
    {
        printf("Member: %d -> priority: %d\n", member, iter->priority);
        member++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("This file is self-compiling\n");

    add_item(1);
    add_item(1);
    add_item(2);
    add_item(3);
    add_item(1);
    add_item(5);
    add_item(4);
    add_item(3);
    remove_item(1);
    remove_item(4);
    remove_item(5);
    add_item(5);

    print_items();
    delete_list();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Bug when inserting item

In `add_item()`, you are missing this code which fixes the `prev` pointer of the node after the one you just inseretd:

```
if (curr != NULL)
    curr->prev = new;
```

#### Bug when removing item

In `remove_item()`, if the node to be removed is the head node, you fail to fix up the `prev` pointer of the second node.  In other words, you need to do the following code in both the head and non-head cases:

```
    if (curr->next)
        curr->next->prev = curr->prev;
```

Comment: Nicely spotted! Can't believe I missed that... Thanks. I have to be careful with doubly linked lists.

Comment: I accepted this answer in case someone wants to use the code, but both answers were acceptance worthy.

Answer (score 7):

All in all there's not much to criticize. Be sure to fix the bugs mentioned in the other answer, though!

---

## Fail fast

```
struct node *new = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
new->priority = priority;
```

You do not check whether allocation succeeded.  Thus the next line will *probably* result in a crash in case `malloc` returned `NULL`.  But it *could* also continue to seem to be working, failing at a potentially completely unrelated point in your program.  That's the problem with undefined behavior. Thus, if you want an allocation failure to be a fatal failure, then you have to actually code such a failure mode:

```
void * malloc_or_die(size_t size) {
  void * pointer = malloc(size);
  if (pointer) {
    return pointer;
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "Fatal: failed to allocate memory of size %zu.\n", size);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

## The trick

> Also, what do you think of my self-compiling trick?

```
//usr/bin/gcc ${0##*/} -o temp && ./temp ; rm temp 2>/dev/null ; exit
```

- Path to compiler hard coded
- Compiler hard coded
- Deletes a possibly existing file `temp` without asking

It's a "trick" that's fun to show once, but really don't use it.  If you want to avoid the sequence of commands to compile, run and possibly delete, then write a shell function to do that for you.

## Global variable

```
struct node *head;
```

You could make your code more general (as in usable for more than one single list instance) if you pass (a pointer to) such a head pointer in to your functions.

## Use blocks

```
    if(curr->next)
        curr->next->prev = curr->prev;
```

Just always use `{ /* ... */ }`.  Saves you from potential headaches when you later add a line of code without looking too closely.

## Consistency

Just some small oddities, nothing of real importance:

- You have `struct node *next;` but also `char** argv`.  Decide whether you want to keep the `*` next to the type or the declared name.
- You test for `(curr != NULL)` but also use `!curr` in a condition later one.  Use either `curr != NULL` and `curr == NULL` or `curr` and `!curr`.

Comment: Another issue with the "trick" - it only works if it's in the current working directory, due to the path removal.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I agree with everything you said. I actually wasn't aware that `malloc` could have undefined behavior. I thought failure to allocate always ended in segfault.